# How to configure libMMS in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, streaming, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, mms

Do anyone know how to configure libMMS for iphone application. I have libMMS library downloaded and I need to configure it in my application. But it gives reference error when I call some function of the library.

Please tell me steps to configure libMMS. I am in the critical situation.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more information about the error that it provides? Is it a linker error? Are you sure that you are linking with a iPhone built library, and not something built for another platform?

Answer (score 1):

Download tuein radio app or wuder radio app.
These app use libmms.
And you can drag their libmms project to your project.

Be sure to observe the LGPL or GPL

Comment: Can you help me how to do that?  I have the code but giving too many errors when integrating.

Comment: And don't forget to add libz.1.dylib file(this file is link file) to your project in framework group.

Comment: This file should not be copied to your project folder. Just reference it